# How to inherit protocols with using MVP?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m newbie and sorry for my english. I’m using MVP pattern. I have common functionality for two screens. And I want to put it into base protocols (BaseVCProtocol and BasePresenterProtocol):

```
protocol BaseVCProtocol: AnyObject {
    var presenter: BasePresenterProtocol? { get set }
    func redraw()
}
extension BaseVCProtocol {
    func redraw() {
        print("BaseVCProtocol redraw")
        presenter?.loadData()
    }
}

protocol BasePresenterProtocol: AnyObject {
    var view: BaseVCProtocol? { get set }
    func configureTitle()
}
extension BasePresenterProtocol {
    func configureTitle() {
        print("BasePresenterProtocol configureTitle")
        view?.redraw()
    }
    func loadData() {
        print("BasePresenterProtocol loadData")
    }
}
```

Also there are child protocols for each screen (FirstVCProtocol, FirstPresenterProtocol and so on):

```
protocol FirstVCProtocol: BaseVCProtocol {
    func showAbsenseAlert()
}
protocol FirstPresenterProtocol: BasePresenterProtocol {
    func configureAnswer()
}
```

I created classes for view and presenter and want to them have access to functionality of base and child protocols, but get compiler error:

```
class VC1: UIViewController, FirstVCProtocol { // error - Type 'VC1' does not conform to protocol 'BaseVCProtocol'
    var presenter: FirstPresenterProtocol?
    func showAbsenseAlert() {
        print("vc1 showAbsenseAlert")
        presenter?.configureAnswer()
    }
}

class Presenter1: FirstPresenterProtocol { // error - Type 'Presenter1' does not conform to protocol 'BasePresenterProtocol'
    weak var view: FirstVCProtocol?
    func configureAnswer() {
        print("Presenter1 configureAnswer")
        view?.showAbsenseAlert()
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Update. Initial problem with duplicated code. First screen:

```
// --- First module MVP--- //
protocol FirstVCProtocol: AnyObject {
    func redraw()
    func showTitle()
    func showVariants()
    func selectAnswer()
}
protocol FirstPresenterProtocol {
    func loadData()
    func configureTitle()
    func getVariants()
    func saveData()
}
class VC1: UIViewController, FirstVCProtocol {
    var presenter: FirstPresenterProtocol?
    func redraw() {
        print("duplicated code here")
        presenter?.configureTitle()
    }
    func showTitle() {
        print("duplicated code here")
    }
    func showVariants() {
        print("VC1 showVariants")
    }
    func selectAnswer() {
        print("VC1 selectAnswer")
        presenter?.saveData()
    }
    func someFuncV1() {
        print("VC1 someFunc")
    }
}
class Presenter1: FirstPresenterProtocol {
    weak var view: FirstVCProtocol?
    func loadData() {
        print("duplicated code here")
        view?.redraw()
    }
    func configureTitle() {
        print("duplicated code here")
        view?.showTitle()
    }
    func getVariants() {
        print("Presenter1 getVariants")
        view?.showVariants()
    }
    func saveData() {
        print("Presenter1 saveData")
    }
    func someFuncP1() {
        print("Presenter1 someFunc")
    }
}
```

Second screen:

```
// --- Second module --- //
protocol SecondVCProtocol: AnyObject {
    func redraw()
    func showTitle()
    func showResults()
}
protocol SecondPresenterProtocol {
    func loadData()
    func configureTitle()
    func getResults()
}
class VC2: UIViewController, SecondVCProtocol {
    var presenter: SecondPresenterProtocol?
    func redraw() {
        print("duplicated code here")
        presenter?.configureTitle()
    }
    func showTitle() {
        print("duplicated code here")
    }
    func showResults() {
        print("VC2 showResults")
    }
    func someFuncV2() {
        print("VC2 someFunc")
    }
}
class Presenter2: SecondPresenterProtocol {
    weak var view: SecondVCProtocol?
    func loadData() {
        print("duplicated code here")
        view?.redraw()
    }
    func configureTitle() {
        print("duplicated code here")
        view?.showTitle()
    }
    func getResults() {
        print("Presenter2 getResults")
        view?.showResults()
    }
    func someFuncP2() {
        print("Presenter2 someFunc")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `baseVCProtocol` requires that all conforming types have a readwrite `presenter` property of type `basePresenterProtocol?`. Your `vc1` does not have that. It has a readwrite property of type `firstPresenterProtocol?`. For a read-write property this can't work. The protocol requires that you be allowed to assign anything of type `basePresenterProtocol?` to this property. That said, Swift also does not allow this for get-only requirements (that's just a current Swift limitation; it may change).

Comment: To make this work, `presenter` needs to be get-only in the protocol, and must return the type `basePresenterProtocol?` in `vc1`. (Please capitalize your types; it's very confusing to see types with leading lowercase letters. It should be Presenter1, FirstPresenterProtocol, etc. Variables and methods have leading lowercase.)

Comment: @Rob Napier Oh, sorry for my lowercase letters, I fixed. So, if presenter will be BasePresenterProtocol? in VC1 - I won't to access to functionality of FirstPresenterProtocol. E.g. presenter?.configureAnswer() will be error. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Have two properties. One private one for internal use that is the specific presenter, and one that allows you to conform to the protocol. You can also use associated types, but before going down that road, you need to ask yourself what these protocols are really for. You may be trying to recreate inheritance with protocols, when that's not useful (protocols encourage composition, not inheritance). Do you really have multiple conforming types to FirstVCProtocol? If VC1 is the only thing that conforms to FirstVCProtocol, then get rid of the protocol.

Comment: The key point is that protocols typically should come out of concrete code that duplicates. Don't make protocols "just in case." `BaseVCProtocol` is incredibly suspicious because it sounds like an abstract class. It's not a collection of capabilities. Given its requirements, it sounds like it should have been called `Presentable` or `DrawableByPresenter` (like `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`). Protocols are about applying algorithms. They're not about type hierarchies.

Comment: @Rob Napier Yes, VC1 is the only one that conforms to FirstVCProtocol. My problem is MVP. I create usually one module MVP for each screen, and View and Presenter at this module must communicate to each other through protocols. But it so happened that there was a lot of the same code in two modules. And I wanted to remove this code into some base view and presenter. But at the same time, so that the presenter and the view can refer to each other everywhere. It seems I made it difficult for myself)

Comment: "must communicate to each other through protocols." Why? If there's only one implementation of a protocol, then you should just pass the thing itself. You can absolutely share code with protocols and extensions; that's an excellent use of protocols. But there's no reason to make thing abstract when they're not abstract. When you use protocols just to share code (rather than to pass things around), then associated types become powerful rather than a headache.

Comment: I'm trying to write up some examples of how you should do this, but the trouble is there's no duplicated code in your example. Try writing VC1/Presenter1 and VC2/Presenter2, and show what kind of duplicated code you're encountering (you can bury all the duplication into a simple `print("duplicated code here")`; you don't have to demonstrate it all). Building a protocol without first knowing what duplication you're trying to fix is "putting the cart before the horse" (as the idiom goes).

Comment: @Rob Napier As I understand in MVP presenter doesn’t know what class is View, and vice versa (may be in future I will change this class to other), and for this they communicate to each other through protocols (protocols will not change). I added code to show my initial problem with duplicate code

Comment: I'm deleting the answer I wrote below. It's not actually very helpful, and is too much me whining about not liking the design. (I don't, but it's not an objectively bad design or anything. I just don't think it works well in today's Swift. And I don't like complex architectures.) The answer didn't even work because it was infinitely recursive. Best of luck. This will get a bit easier over the next few iterations of Swift.

Comment: @Rob Napier  Ok, thanks for trying to help me